# zsh `getopts` OPTIND behavior not consistent with other shells (bash, sh)

Tags: shell, zsh, getopts

The definition of `$OPTIND` in POSIX shell, bash are quite consistent and intuitive - it is the index of the next arg to be read. However, its behavior in `zsh` is quite puzzling, and I can't find document for it.

Example:

```
# ./test.sh:
foo() {
    while getopts "1:2:34:" flag; do
        echo flag: $flag
        echo arg: $OPTARG
        echo ind: $OPTIND
    done &&
    echo .
}

foo -1 1 -2 2 -3 3 -4 4
```

Now execute:

```
>>> sh ./test.sh
flag: 1
arg: 1
ind: 3
flag: 2
arg: 2
ind: 5
flag: 3
arg:
ind: 6    <<<< EXPECTED - next arg should be $6
.

>>> bash ./test.sh
flag: 1
arg: 1
ind: 3
flag: 2
arg: 2
ind: 5
flag: 3
arg:
ind: 6    <<<< EXPECTED - next arg should be $6
.

>>> zsh ./test.sh 
flag: 1
arg: 1
ind: 3
flag: 2
arg: 2
ind: 5
flag: 3
arg:
ind: 5   <<<<<< NOTICE HERE
.
```

This is tested on `zsh 5.3.1 (amd64-portbld-freebsd11.0)`

Answer (score 2):

You should not care much about the value of `OPTIND`.

What's important is the next argument after all the options are processed:

Following structure works the same way for both bash and zsh:

```
# ./test.sh:
foo() {
    local OPTIND flag
    while getopts "1:2:34:" flag; do
        echo flag: $flag
        echo arg: $OPTARG
        echo ind: $OPTIND
    done 
    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
    echo "Next arg is $1"
}

foo -1 1 -2 2 -3 3 -4 4
```

Always include `local OPTIND` in any function that use `getopts`
otherwise all `getopts` share a single global `OPTIND`

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted. While this particular type of usage of OPTIND works, it still doesn't answer my original question of why. Shifting `OPTIND-1` at the end of the loop isn't the only way of using `getopts`, it's just a commonly used pattern. So in the cases when OPTIND used differently, my concern in the original question still holds, unless this behavior is understood more clearly.

Comment: Can you give an example use case where OPTIND is used differently and which cannot be covered by the pattern I gave?

Comment: That solution did not work for me. `getopts` is still unreliable in zsh. I used a while loop instead of `getopts`.